# How to access SQL Server scalar functions in MS Access VB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to find out how I can access scalar functions from the SQL Server database of my adp file.

I have an adp file in access 2007 and a SQL Server 2005 DB.

In access VB I try to get the result of a scalar function with parameters.

I tried with DAO, but it that case currentdb = nothing:

```
  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Dim sql2 As String
  Dim txt As String
  Dim iCount As Integer

  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  txt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_Klanten" '(tbl_klanten is in the msql DB) '
  dbs.Execute txt, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Also, your use of the term "scalar" in the subject is misleading. Scalar implies the result is one single value.

Comment: CurrentDB *never* Is Nothing, as it always returns a new database object. But it's not relevant in an ADP, which can't use Jet, and has to use ADO.

Answer (score 0):

DAO was never designed to access sql server even though its possible.

I believe the CurrentDB property is a DAO connection referencing the access database, and may not work with ADP, even though I don't really know since I've never used them.

ADO is the way you want to go with this.

I'm also assuming you're sticking with VBA rather than doing anything with .NET.

[ADO API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086(v=VS.85).aspx)

[ADO Objects reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679836(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: DAO can't access SQL Server directly, but it certainly can via ODBC.