# Need to fetch returned value from SQL procedure in Access recordset

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, recordset

I am new in Access and I am stuck in recordsets. I am running a procedure from Access using correct connection string. The procedure is running perfectly fine.

```
Set con = New ADODB.connection  
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset  
con.Open "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                // Connection string.  
rs.Open "Exec [stored procedure] 'parameter' ", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

This stored procedure in SQL returns two values 0 and 1 on the basis of failure and success (which tells the status of procedure).

Now my question is how to fetch this value in access so that I can show user the status.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your stored procedure actually returns only one value, which will either be 0 or 1. This is often referred to as a scalar value (a single value instead of a set or collection of values).

It also looks like you need to pass parameters to your stored procedure. This is often referred to as a parameterized query. As you probably well know, it's possible to write stored procedures that do not not use parameters.

```vb
Set con = New ADODB.connection  
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
rs.LockType = adLockReadOnly
con.Open "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" '// Connection string.

Dim cmd as New ADODb.Command
cmd.CommandTimeout = 5
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "SQL GOES HERE"
cmd.CommandType = acCmdStoredProc

Dim param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@productid", adInteger, adParamInput, 0, 0)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
cmd.Parameters("@productid") = 15 'Return the product with ProductID = 15

Set rs = cmd.Execute
'or use:
'rs.Open cmd
Debug.Print rs(0)

rs.close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
con.close
Set con = Nothing
```

Microsoft has an article on this. It's written using VBScript but can be easily adapted to VBA.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190

You might also check out this on SO:
[How to access SQL Server scalar functions in MS Access VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070067/how-to-access-sql-server-scalar-functions-in-ms-access-vb)

Answer (score 0):

When calling a Stored Procedure, the 1st parameter is the return value.

```
' Set up a return parameter.
Set prm = .CreateParameter("Return", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
.Parameters.Append prm
 ' Set up an input parameter.
Set prm = .CreateParameter("Id", adInteger, adParamInput, , lid)
.Parameters.Append prm
' Set up an output parameter.
Set prm = .CreateParameter("Output", adInteger, adParamOutput)
.Parameters.Append prm

' Execute command, and loop through recordset, printing out rows.
.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
If .Parameters("Return") = 0 Then
    lid = Nz(.Parameters("Output").Value, 0)
    If lid <> 0 Then AdoSingleId = True
Else
    lid = .Parameters("Return")
End If
```